# mathematical row operation on a dataframe

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dataframe, numpy-ndarray

I have a very large labelled dictionary array dataframe, df of dimension (9  by 4500) with index `[1,2,3,...,4500]`. I intend to carry out the following respective mathematical row operation element-by-element on the dataframe:

```
[ 0.          0.00000771  0.00006065 ... 79.96962749 79.96969808
 79.96976853]
[0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
[0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
[0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
[0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
[0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
[0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
[0. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
```

## For mu1, considering the 1st row:

```
= [ 0.*0          0.00000771*1  0.00006065*2 ... 79.96962749*4497
    79.96969808*4498  79.96976853*4499] # 'n' is the index number
```

## For mu2, considering the 1st row:

```
= [ 0.*(0)**2          0.00000771*(1)**2  0.00006065*(2)**2 ... 79.96962749*(4497)**2 79.96969808* 
   (4498)**2  79.96976853*(4499)**2] # 'n' is the index number
```

Here is the code I implemented but do not get what I expected:

```
##calculating mu1:
n=10
for x in range(1,n):
mu1=df.apply(lambda x: x if x.name in [1,2,3,...,4500] else x,axis =1)
mu1

## calculating mu2:
n=10
for x in range(1,n):
mu2=df.apply(lambda x:(x**2) if x.name in [1,2,3,...,4500] else x,axis =1)
mu2
```

I presume my code might be wrong.

Comment: Did you get the result that you want through your code?

Comment: first remark, you use the variable x for the `for` loop and the same variable x in the `apply`, avoid this. Now, I understand that the shape of your dataframe is 9 rows for 4500 columns? also why do you check `if x.name in [...]`, what is the point in the calculation of mu1 as in both case you return x? and actually why you use `for` loop?

Comment: sorry for the late response @ Ben.T.  I quite understand what you meant. I am currently working on @Kevin Choon Liang Yew's view to converting the data to a NumPy array before manipulating the data. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest first converting your dataframe to numpy array for ease of handling (It's my own preference)

```
array = np.array(df)

mu1, mu2 = [],[]

#mu1 and mu2 calculation
for i in array:
    mu1.append([number * index for index, number in enumerate(i)])
    mu2.append([number * index ** 2 for index, number in enumerate(i)])
```

Or even easier, just do vector multiplication:

```
index = np.array(range(4500))

mu1 = array * index
mu2 = array * index ** 2
```

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Thank you very much @Kevin Choon Liang Yew

Comment: Glad it helps! Please also help to mark this answer as correct. Thank you :-D